# how to read xml nodes with same name in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, element

how to read xml nodes with same name in c#?

I have XML file with a users, and their personal informations(name, surname, age, photos...).

I'm displaying this infos in gridview, and everything is ok. Just cannot select one photo to display in the gridview, one photo for every user, like profile photo. I cannot do this cause there is not a tag .

There are more tags with same name  like in example below. So i'm trying to select all infos, put in datatable, and display in gridview control with Eval("Foto") functioon.

But photos cannot be displayd because in evel function cannot be inserted more photos in same time.

This is the structure of the photos in the XML document:

```
<User>

<Name>User name</Name>
<Surname>User surname</Surname>

<Foto>
  http://website.com/images/image1.jpg
</Foto>

<Foto>
  http://website.com/images/image2.jpg
</Foto>

<Foto>
  http://website.com/images/image3.jpg
</Foto>

<Foto>
  http://website.com/images/image4.jpg
</Foto>

</User>
```

This is the gridview control which i use

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ShowFooter="false" ShowHeader="false" CssClass="tablepress-id-N" runat="server" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"    OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging"  onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>

         <li class="objectListItem">

   <div style="float:left;width:12%;margin-right:5%;">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Foto")%>'></asp:Image>

   </div>


        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>
        <pagerstyle cssclass="gridviewPager"></pagerstyle>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Where i make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The XML document structure is iteself a mistake. It should be like

```
<User>

<Name>User name</Name>
<Surname>User surname</Surname>
<photos>
<photo>
  http://website.com/images/image1.jpg
</photo>

<photo>
  http://website.com/images/image2.jpg
</photo>

<photo>
  http://website.com/images/image3.jpg
</photo>

<photo>
  http://website.com/images/image4.jpg
</photo>
</photos>
</User>
```

Now in the backend you should pickup one element from  list and pass one  to Gridview.